# Update Input while mapping in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to ReactJS, I'm trying to update input value to a different one however, for some reason it is not updating as it should be, I've got the code on stackblitz for more explanation if you want to try it out as it is performing a very strange behaviour.
Appreciate your assistance.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/easy-drag-and-drop-fxs217?file=index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
  myArray: [
    [123, 364],
    [469, 983]
  ]
};

this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);

}

handleInputChange(e, index) {
let updatedState = [...this.state.myArray];
 console.log("updatedstate ", updatedState)
 console.log(e.target.value)
 updatedState[index] = [Number(e.target.value), this.state.myArray[index][1]]
 this.setState=({
   myArray: updatedState
 })
}

render() {
 return (
  <div>
    {this.state.myArray.map((item, index) => (
      <input key={index} type="text" value={item[0]} onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, 
       index)} />
    ))}
  </div>
  );
 }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You should update state only with `this.setState()` method.

Comment: What you want to do here>>>>>updatedState[index] = [Number(e.target.value), this.state.myArray[index][1]]<<<< Plus you are not setting the sate anywhere...

Comment: ....you don't set the state anywhere lol. At the end of you `handleInputChange` function you need to update the state like so: `this.setState({ myArray: updatedState});`. P.S. the spread operator doesn't do DEEP clones, and currently your function actually mutates the state array. In this case it won't really be an issue, but in some instances can cause buggy behaviour so just keep it in mind

Comment: Thanx for your Stackblitz link . But can you explain a bit clearly wht you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Sure, When I type in anything inside the input field it does not reflect, so all I want is just to type in the input normally

Comment: @Sa1m0n I've updated my code but still same behaviour

Comment: Remove the `=` after `this.setState`. Also make sure it's `myArray: updatedState` as you have it here. Your stackblitz snippet works if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

### SOLUTION

1. Pick the part of your array for which to update by index.
2. Update it with the new value.
3. Use the same array to update your state.

```
  handleInputChange(e, index) {
    let arrayPart = this.state.myArray[index];
    arrayPart[0] = Number(e.target.value) || null;
  
    this.setState({
      myArray: this.state.myArray,
    })
  }
```